# Rudin's RCA, Euclidean Spaces $\delta$-box

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

[image]

I don't understand why are the $(a)$ and part of the $(c)$ obvious.

In $(c)$ I understand that why is vol$(Q)$ equal of $2^{-rk}$. But I don't understand why does the set $p_n$ have $2^{(n-r)k}$ points in $Q$ when $n$ $\gt$ $r$.

I would be grateful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

$(a)$ The collection $\Omega_n$ covers $R^k$ so that $x$ is in at least one of its elements. These elements are pairwise disjoint so that $x$ cannot be in more than one of them.

$(c)$ The set $Q \in \Omega_r$ is partitioned by a certain number $N$ of elements $Q_i \in \Omega_n$ when $n>r$, with $i=1,..,N$. All the sets $Q_i$ have the same volume $2^{-nk}$ (by $(c)$ again). Then $$2^{-rk}=vol(Q)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} vol(Q_i)=N \cdot 2^{-nk}$$ so that $N=2^{(n-r)k}$ as claimed.

Comment: Why are these elements pairwise disjoint? look at the $(b)$ in the book.

Comment: They are disjoint for any fixed $n$ (as specified in $(a)$).

Comment: I don't understand what you've just said.

Comment: For a fixed $n$ the collection $\Omega_n$ is a partition of $R^k$.

Comment: Then what? 
How do you assume that these elements are pairwise disjoint?

Comment: By the definition of partition. It should help working out the special cases $k=1, k=2$ to “see” the various $\Omega_n$.